# Cannot connect to Linux services in WSL2 from browser (Windows 10)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, wsl2

I was using WSL2 for sometime and it was all okay - a great experience.

But suddenly I am not able to connect to services in Linux from my browser. I cannot open jupyter notebooks and my pyramid app in Firefox as localhost:xxxx. Also I use ssh-tunneling to access DB on cloud instances; all okay in bash but not visible to desktop apps anymore.

The dockerized services are still accessible / I can open them in browser as localhost without any issues.
Any idea where should I look and what should I check?

Answer (score 2):

The issue happened after running a `wsl --shutdown` to restart my Linux kernel - because the assigned IP to the Linux subsystem was changed.

So I added an interface-level `Allow-All` rule to the Windows Firewall, and it is okay now.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "AllowWSL" -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Action Allow -Direction Inbound
```

Comment: The dockerized services were not an issue, because Docker Desktop manage its own part with separate kernels and services.